# .Net: Inserting with index in a ListView in LargeIcon mode don't display inserted items in right position

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, listview

If i try

```
    ListView1.Sorting = SortOrder.None
    ListView1.ListViewItemSorter = Nothing
    ListView1.Items.Insert(0, "0")
    ListView1.Items.Insert(1, "1")
    ListView1.Items.Insert(0, "2")
    ListView1.Items.Insert(1, "3")
```

If ListView1.View is SmallIcon , LargeIcon or Tile it dont work (Display 0 1 2 3). If it's in List it works (Display desired 2 3 0 1).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, got it myself. Apparently this is a bug in MS ListView, the workaround is resetting the Alignment, forcing a refresh:

```
        ListView1.Alignment = ListViewAlignment.Default
        ListView1.Alignment = ListViewAlignment.Top
```